# xcode: I need to pass an imageView captured in secondView Controller to the first Controller

Tags: ios, xcode

```
 (IBAction)captureButton:(id)sender {

    captureButton.hidden = YES;
    cancelButton.hidden = YES;

    currImage = [signatureViewController imageWithView:self.view];
    NSLog (@"image %@",currImage);
    imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150,100,300,350)];
    imgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    imgView.image = currImage;
    [self.view addSubview:imgView];
}
```

Capturing the imageView now need to pass this to signView in first Controller.

Comment: This is my doneButton Code: clicking on this should place the imageview captured in the first Controller-(IBAction)doneAction:(id)sender
{ [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; NSLog (@"current image %@",currImage);
    imgView.image = currImage;

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the image from one view controller to other view controller in many ways,Out of which some are listed below

1. In the app delegate create one imageview object.Declare property &
       synthesize of it to access it in other classes. Now Create App
       delegate share instance & set the image view object of app delegate
       in captureButton method of second view controller. To access the
       same image again create shared instance of app delegate file in
       first view controller and use the app delegate image view property
       to get the image.
2. Second way is by using the delegates methods

   ```
       //Declare delegate in second view controller
       @protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate

       -(void)setTheImage:(UIImage *)img

       @end

       //Declare property of delegate protocol
       @property (assign)id<SecondViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

       //synthesize the variable 
       @synthesize delegate;


       //Extend SecondViewControllerDelegate in first view controller by importing secondviewController in first view controller
       #import secondviewController.h

           @interface firstviewController : UIViewController<SecondViewControllerDelegate>
   ```

   // Now wherever you are creating object of SecondViewController set the delegate as follows lets say objSecondViewController is object of your view controller

   ```
   objSecondViewController.delegate=(id)self;

   //Now define delegate method of  SecondViewControllerDelegate

   -(void)setTheImage:(UIImage *)img
   {
   //here set the image img to your image view present in first view controller
   }
   //Now lastly in second view controller in captureButton function call the function

   [delegate captureButton:currImage];
   ```
3. Third way is to use the global declaration of the first view
   controller & set the image view in the captureButton by declaring
   the property & synthesize of imageview of first view controller

Answer (score 0):

I Have done this using NSUser defaults..
In the secondViewController:

```
-(IBAction)doneAction:(id)sender
{
    imgView.image = currImage;
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(currImage);
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:imageData forKey:@"imageDataKey"];
    NSLog (@"Data Saved");
}
```

and i have assigned this saved image to the imageview in the firstController in -(void)viewWillAppear: Method